# Imported data not properly separated

Tags: r

So I have an issue that my data in my .CSV file looks like this and it is how I need it, (only difference is I need Time and Date in 2 separate columns).
(EDIT)

Here is the goal format that I need my data to look like in R Studio, other than Separating the timestamp column into a Date and a Time column. (This was copy pasted from EXCEL)

```
timestamp   axis1   axis2   axis3   VM  standing    stepping    sitting
2022-03-17 11:29    0   0   0   0   0   0   1
2022-03-17 11:29    0   0   0   0   0   0   1
2022-03-17 11:29    0   0   0   0   0   0   1
2022-03-17 11:29    0   0   0   0   0   0   1
2022-03-17 11:29    0   0   0   0   0   0   1
2022-03-17 11:29    0   0   0   0   0   0   1
2022-03-17 11:29    0   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

But my data imported at first is all clumped into 1 column,

```
data1 <- read_csv("AE1_07 DBG (2022-03-17)1sec.csv")
1
2022-03-17 11:29:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
2
2022-03-17 11:29:01,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
3
2022-03-17 11:29:02,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
4
2022-03-17 11:29:03,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
5
2022-03-17 11:29:04,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
6
2022-03-17 11:29:05,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
7
2022-03-17 11:29:06,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
8
2022-03-17 11:29:07,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
9
2022-03-17 11:29:08,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
10
2022-03-17 11:29:09,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
11
2022-03-17 11:29:10,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
12
2022-03-17 11:29:11,124,72,61,155.82,0,0,1
13
2022-03-17 11:29:12,195,121,101,250.73,0,0,1
14
2022-03-17 11:29:13,36,21,0,41.68,0,0,1
15
2022-03-17 11:29:14,72,184,91,217.53,0,0,1
16
2022-03-17 11:29:15,80,145,53,173.88,0,0,1
```

Here is the "raw" data when I open the file in NotePad

```
timestamp,axis1,axis2,axis3,vectormagnitude,inclinestanding,inclinestepping,inclinesittinglying
2022-03-11 17:00:00,139,15,19,141.09,0,0,1
2022-03-11 17:00:01,183,15,10,183.89,0,0,1
2022-03-11 17:00:02,185,0,21,186.19,0,0,1
2022-03-11 17:00:03,184,12,20,185.47,0,0,1
2022-03-11 17:00:04,183,13,19,184.44,0,0,1
2022-03-11 17:00:05,179,12,21,180.63,0,0,1
```

Comment: Your first block here is the raw file, right? There are no commas, why are you using `read_csv`?

Comment: Yes, I am using read_csv, it is just copy pasted from Excel

Comment: correction ... ***why*** are you using `read_csv` when your data is not comma-separated?

Comment: because it's a .CSV file generated by a software I'm using? so I would of assumed the data is comma-separated ? When the data is imported it has commas separating the data points but it is not separating it.

Comment: `.csv` file extension does not make it CSV. There is a bit of confusion here: I see commas in the second code block, but that suggests that every other line of your file has a single number, which will not work with R csv readers. If instead your first code block is the file, then it is not CSV. So I'm confused. Can you be clear which (if either) of your blocks above has the *raw contents of the file*? It's important that it not be read/parsed by R to be sure what should be used to read it ... even the, Stack is going to "hide" tab characters if present.

Comment: I've edited the question, let me know if this is still unclear. I checked and the values are comma-separated if I open the file in notepad as well

Comment: That is what I suspect: *neither* of your code blocks are the raw file. If my answer below does not work, then please paste the raw contents of the file (at least the first few rows) into a code block, do not try to copy/paste from Excel. Sometimes the raw contents are the simplest to work with.

Comment: I've added  what I think is the "raw content" please let me know if that is not what you're looking for and how to get it.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that's better, but ... your new raw content and the failure in your code make no sense to me. When I take that and run `readr::read_csv("quux.csv")` and `read.csv("quux.csv")`, I get clean frames. There must be something else with your file that is not being represented correctly here.

Comment: Ok thanks, I figured it out, There was a column with a few rows of information on the file at the top that was forcing the rest of the file to go into one column, fixed now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your *second* code block is the real raw file, then we'll have some problems, since the interleaved single-number rows will require with external manipulation or a less performant `readLines(.)` step in R before parsing it correctly. I'll skip this possibility for the moment ...

If the *first* code block is the real raw file, then we have two possibilities:

1. If it is really tab-delimited (where the only spaces are in the `timestamp` field between the date and time), then we can simply use `read.table`. I'll start with a file `quux.tsv` that has mostly tabs.

   ```r
   dat <- read.table("quux.tsv", header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
   dat
   #          timestamp axis1 axis2 axis3 VM standing stepping sitting
   # 1 2022-03-17 11:29     0     0     0  0        0        0       1
   # 2 2022-03-17 11:29     0     0     0  0        0        0       1
   # 3 2022-03-17 11:29     0     0     0  0        0        0       1
   # 4 2022-03-17 11:29     0     0     0  0        0        0       1
   # 5 2022-03-17 11:29     0     0     0  0        0        0       1
   # 6 2022-03-17 11:29     0     0     0  0        0        0       1
   # 7 2022-03-17 11:29     0     0     0  0        0        0       1
   ```

   and we can split `timestamp` using:

   ```r
   dat$date <- sub(" .*", "", dat$timestamp)
   dat$time <- sub(".* ", "", dat$timestamp)
   dat$timestamp <- NULL
   dat
   #   axis1 axis2 axis3 VM standing stepping sitting       date  time
   # 1     0     0     0  0        0        0       1 2022-03-17 11:29
   # 2     0     0     0  0        0        0       1 2022-03-17 11:29
   # 3     0     0     0  0        0        0       1 2022-03-17 11:29
   # 4     0     0     0  0        0        0       1 2022-03-17 11:29
   # 5     0     0     0  0        0        0       1 2022-03-17 11:29
   # 6     0     0     0  0        0        0       1 2022-03-17 11:29
   # 7     0     0     0  0        0        0       1 2022-03-17 11:29
   ```
2. If it is (multi-)space delimited, though, I'll use a `quux.txt` file that has no tabs, just multiple spaces as in your first block.

   ```r
   dat <- fread("quux.txt")
   # Warning in fread("quux.txt") :
   #   Detected 8 column names but the data has 9 columns (i.e. invalid file). Added 1 extra default column name for the first column which is guessed to be row names or an index. Use setnames() afterwards if this guess is not correct, or fix the file write command that created the file to create a valid file.
   dat
   #            V1 timestamp axis1 axis2 axis3    VM standing stepping sitting
   #        <IDat>    <char> <int> <int> <int> <int>    <int>    <int>   <int>
   # 1: 2022-03-17     11:29     0     0     0     0        0        0       1
   # 2: 2022-03-17     11:29     0     0     0     0        0        0       1
   # 3: 2022-03-17     11:29     0     0     0     0        0        0       1
   # 4: 2022-03-17     11:29     0     0     0     0        0        0       1
   # 5: 2022-03-17     11:29     0     0     0     0        0        0       1
   # 6: 2022-03-17     11:29     0     0     0     0        0        0       1
   # 7: 2022-03-17     11:29     0     0     0     0        0        0       1
   ```

   That warning is a little annoying, but *in this case* it can be ignored, even suppressed using `suppressWarnings(fread("quux.txt"))`. From there, it has already split `timestamp` (conveniently, but indicating a "problem" with the format, ergo the warning), you just need to rename the columns.

   An alternative uses a one-line preprocessing to split the word `timestamp` in the header row so that most parsers will read it correctly.

   ```r
   Sys.which("sed")
   #                               sed 
   # "c:\\rtools40\\usr\\bin\\sed.exe" 
   system("sed -i -e '1 s/timestamp/time stamp/' quux.txt")
   # [1] 0
   ```

   (Most unix-y OSes have `sed` in the path, and windows does by virtue of having Rtools installed ... your location may vary.)

   Breakdown:

   ```
   -i -e '1 s/timestamp/time stamp/'
    ^                               edit/change in-place
       ^                            evaluate the next expression
          ^                         this expression only on line 1
            ^ `-------' `--------'  search/replace
   ```

   This needs to be done only once per file; it is harmless to run again, but there should be no change since `timestamp` will have already been changed and will no longer be found.

   From here, most readers will see it just fine, such as

   ```r
   read.table("quux.txt", header = TRUE)
   #         time stamp axis1 axis2 axis3 VM standing stepping sitting
   # 1 2022-03-17 11:29     0     0     0  0        0        0       1
   # 2 2022-03-17 11:29     0     0     0  0        0        0       1
   # 3 2022-03-17 11:29     0     0     0  0        0        0       1
   # 4 2022-03-17 11:29     0     0     0  0        0        0       1
   # 5 2022-03-17 11:29     0     0     0  0        0        0       1
   # 6 2022-03-17 11:29     0     0     0  0        0        0       1
   # 7 2022-03-17 11:29     0     0     0  0        0        0       1
   readr::read_table("quux.txt")
   # -- Column specification ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   # cols(
   #   time = col_date(format = ""),
   #   stamp = col_time(format = ""),
   #   axis1 = col_double(),
   #   axis2 = col_double(),
   #   axis3 = col_double(),
   #   VM = col_double(),
   #   standing = col_double(),
   #   stepping = col_double(),
   #   sitting = col_double()
   # )
   # # A tibble: 7 x 9
   #   time       stamp  axis1 axis2 axis3    VM standing stepping sitting
   #   <date>     <time> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
   # 1 2022-03-17 11:29      0     0     0     0        0        0       1
   # 2 2022-03-17 11:29      0     0     0     0        0        0       1
   # 3 2022-03-17 11:29      0     0     0     0        0        0       1
   # 4 2022-03-17 11:29      0     0     0     0        0        0       1
   # 5 2022-03-17 11:29      0     0     0     0        0        0       1
   # 6 2022-03-17 11:29      0     0     0     0        0        0       1
   # 7 2022-03-17 11:29      0     0     0     0        0        0       1
   ```